# How to send post request to server.js in cloud9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, cloud9-ide

Hi I'm learning the mean stack on cloud9.

I've come to the point where I'm trying to send variables to my node.js server but I'm not sure if my server is picking it up. Are there any obvious errors with my post request code?

app.js(frontend angular)

```
console.log('begin');
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "text=stuff";
    http.open("POST", "https://new-backup.splacorn.c9.io/myApp/server/server.js/", true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log('onreadystatechange');
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
        else {
        console.log('readyState=' + http.readyState + ', status: ' + http.status);
    }
}

console.log('sending...')
http.send(params);
console.log('end');
```

this is the console response that I am getting:

```
begin
sending...
end
POST https://new-backup.splacorn.c9.io/myApp/server/server.js/ net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE$scope.addNewUser

onreadystatechange
readyState=4, status: 0
```

I believe that the error that I am getting is attributed to this line:

```
http.open("POST", "https://new-backup.splacorn.c9.io/myApp/server/server.js/", true);
```

once `http.send(params);` calls it.

Here is the server.js file (backend)

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('POST /');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('this is from the server');
});

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the error? Part of me thinks that I'm getting the cloud 9 server url wrong but I'm not sure... If anyone can help me figure this out that would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use socket.io instead.
Here's a small example of how you can do it:-
Client side code:

```
var io = io("http://localhost:1337");
io.emit('give me some data',{test:'testing socket.io'});
io.on('got the data',function(data){
    console.log(data.test);
});
```

Server side code:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
     socket.on('give me some data',function(data){
               socket.emit('got the data',data);
      }
app.listen(1337);
```

You can get socket.io [here](http://socket.io)
They have both client side as well as server side code. Hope you got my point. I was at phone so couldn't type much. And also, socket.io provides real time connection between the client and the server :)

Comment: Thanks! socket.io seems down right now but I'll definitely try it